# How to make a clear SwiftUI view block the scrollview underneath it

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, vstack, hstack

So I have a ZStack that contains a ScrollView on the bottom and an HStack that's aligned at the top. It looks something like this:

```
ZStack {
  ScrollView {
    //Content
  }
  VStack {
    HStack {
      Spacer()
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
      Spacer()
    }
    Spacer()
  }
}
```

Now, I want that HStack to block any interaction with the ScrollView beneath it. I've noticed that when I set the background on the HStack to a non-clear color, it behaves as I'd like it to. However, if the background is clear, then the touches go through the HStack and interact with the ScrollView beneath it. I've also tried using .allowsHitTesting(true) on the HStack with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jzby.png
```

Answer (score 1):

"...I've noticed that when I set the background on the HStack to a non-clear color, it behaves as I'd like it to.", then you could use `Color.white.opacity(0.001)`
instead of `Color.clear or non-clear color`

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I was hoping for a more refined solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by putting it in a `VStack` instead of a `ZStack`. The touches will be ignored as it's above the `ScrollView`. You can also have a look at `.layoutPriority()`, it may also be useful. Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/layoutpriority(_:)).

[image: scrollview]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            // or this does the same thing as the HStack two spacers
            /*
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
             */
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(1..<11) { value in
                    Text("\(value)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use this, because I still want to see the elements layered in the ZStack.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot on how you want it to look using a ZStack. I’ll update my answer

Comment: Hi, sorry on the late reply--the red part is the scroll view, with an HStack containing a circle at the top of the stack. I want to make the entire HStack block the scrolling when the drag starts there.